# With Java HttpClient, how to handle responses other than 200 (SUCCESS)?

Tags: java, spring-resttemplate, java-http-client

When using rest template we can handle response statuses other than 200 based on the exception thrown by resttemplate. This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling) describes this in detail.

```
By default, the RestTemplate will throw one of these exceptions in the case of an HTTP error:

HttpClientErrorException – in the case of HTTP status 4xx
HttpServerErrorException – in the case of HTTP status 5xx
UnknownHttpStatusCodeException – in the case of an unknown HTTP status
```

Is a similar approach possible when using java `HttpClient`. I am using [JSONBodyHandler](https://github.com/mjg123/java-http-clients/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/JsonBodyHandler.java) approach to automatically serialize the response into a pojo.

```
// create a client
var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

// create a request
var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(
       URI.create("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"))
   .header("accept", "application/json")
   .build();

// use the client to send the request
var response = client.send(request, new JsonBodyHandler<>(APOD.class));

APOD apod = response.body().get();
```

The above works well when the response is 200 but it does not work when there is some server error or client error.

Say for a client error, with an incorrect api key in the request (i.e query param i.e api_key=Incorrect_KEY),
`curl --location 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=INCORRECT_KEY'` the response from server is `403`  -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "message": "An invalid api_key was supplied. Get one at https://api.nasa.gov:443"
    }
}
```

The above is definitely different from `APOD.class` structure and cannot be deserialzed in to this class. I don't see any exception being thrown  by `HttpClient` and as `Jackson` tries to deserialze it throws `UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "error"` and every thing fails. The error response message: *An invalid api_key was supplied...etc*, from server is important for me so i can correct and resent the request.

How to handle above cases of SUCCESS and ERROR responses from server using the same code flow.

*(I am NOT looking at `BodyHandlers.ofString()` approach as I want to continue using the JSONBodyHandler approach.)*

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to check the response before reading the response body. Based on the result (success or failure) you will need to handle the response differently. For success de-serialize your JSON response into your POJO, and for the error obviously you will have a different handling.

If you want to see the example you can take a look at the code of a 3d party HttpClient that I wrote. It comes as part of Open source MgntUtuls library written and maintained by me. You can look at the source code on Git [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) (or download the library, source code and Javadoc from [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)). By the way library also has a `JsonUtils` class that simplifies simple cases for serialization/de-serialization of JSON to POJO. you can take a look at [Javadoc](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/) or download library as maven artifact from [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils).

Comment: could you plz give the **code** link where the above mentioned is implemented..

Comment: It's in class HttpClient. See the source code: https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.java

Comment: Michael, thanks for the ref +1. But that code is using [HttpURLConnection](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/blob/493f87029f1570d3f3ee7c5f4673e7f624b41921/src/main/java/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.java#L302). I am looking for the JDK `HttpClient` based code

Comment: @CodeBot You are correct but the idea should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Check the responses status code - that's what you are indicating anyway. But even if it is different than 200 you can still evaluate the response body.

Comment: even for 400/500 statuses this line -> `var response = client.send(request, new JsonBodyHandler<>(APOD.class))` will try to convert the error response and fail..  while with `rest template` 400/500 will result in to exception which can be handled in a different way than the success response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try new a parent class for APOD and other response class which contains error field.